# How do I install ActiveMQ as a 64-bit Service on windows?

Tags: java, windows, activemq-classic

How can I get around the following error?
Is there a way I can copy a 64-bit wrapper out there?

```
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2011/01/07 08:53:48 | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/01/07 08:54:13 | ActiveMQ installed.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/01/07 08:54:25 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 | WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library 'wrapper.dll'.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           The file is located on the path at the following location but
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           could not be loaded:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |             C:\stuff\apache-activemq-5.4.2\bin\win32\..\..\bin\win32\wrapper.dll
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           Please verify that the file is readable by the current user
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           and that the file has not been corrupted in any way.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           One common cause of this problem is running a 32-bit version
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           of the Wrapper with a 64-bit version of Java, or vica versa.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           This is a 64-bit JVM.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           Reported cause:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |             C:\stuff\apache-activemq-5.4.2\bin\win32\wrapper.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |           System signals will not be handled correctly.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/07 08:54:26 |
```

Comment: Questions like this which are less about programming and more about server administration belong on a site like ServerFault rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Procrun since the wrapper.dll for 64-bit isn't free.

http://blog.bigrocksoftware.com/2010/10/07/commons-daemon-procrun-as-a-java-service-wrapper-for-activemq/

Already tried the article's setup in our production. It works great!

Answer (score 19):

I managed to install ActiveMQ successfully as a service on Windows 7 without having to download anything else. You just need to modify a few config settings.

If you go into the following folder: C:\apache-activemq-5.5.0\bin\win32

Open the "InstallService.bat" file in a local text editor.

Modify the bottom part of the script to look like the following. Notice that your JAVA_HOME environment variable needs to already be set and you'll need to pass it as a variable to the wrapper.

```
:conf
set _WRAPPER_CONF="%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%\bin\win32\wrapper.conf"

set _ACTIVEMQ_HOME="set.ACTIVEMQ_HOME=%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%"
set _ACTIVEMQ_BASE="set.ACTIVEMQ_BASE=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%"
set _JAVA_HOME="set.JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"

rem
rem Install the Wrapper as an NT service.
rem
:startup
"%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%\bin\win32\wrapper.exe" -i %_WRAPPER_CONF% %_ACTIVEMQ_HOME% %_ACTIVEMQ_BASE% %_JAVA_HOME%
if not errorlevel 1 goto :eof
pause
```

Then open up "C:\apache-activemq-5.5.0\bin\win32\wrapper.conf" in a local text editor

And change this:

```
# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=java
```

to this:

```
# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

**Once you've done that you should be able to run the InstallService.bat successfully.**

Also, if you want to be able to use the UninstallService.bat file as well, open it up and hard code the path to the wrapper as well:

```
rem
rem Uninstall the Wrapper as an NT service.
rem
:startup
"%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%\bin\win32\wrapper.exe" -r %_WRAPPER_CONF%
if not errorlevel 1 goto :eof
pause
```

**ActiveMQ 5.6.0 notes**
I just installed the latest 5.6.0 version of ActiveMQ and it actually contains a 64-bit wrapper in this version. If you try clicking on the InstallService.bat file it will still fail unfortunately giving you an error like this:
[image: InstallService.bat error].

If you open a windows command prompt as an administrator and run the InstallService.bat file from the command line it will work. Otherwise if you absolutely insist on being able to click the bat file it will work if you modify the bat files as above except remember to use win64 in this line instead of win32:

```
"%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%\bin\win64\wrapper.exe"
```

Comment: Got my hopes up for a while, but ultimately didn't work for me.

Comment: This def works on Windows 7, I've installed it on about 10 different machines now and it seems to work fine on all of them.. I'll have another look at my bat file and make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: This does not work for 64-bit Windows 7. I have tried this on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise edition with ActiveMQ 5.4.3 and 5.5.1.

You will need a 64-bit wrapper that isn't available in the community edition at this moment.

Comment: Agreed I haven't been able to have the same success with 5.5.1, this seems to only work with 5.5.0.. unlucky.. :(

Comment: This works with 5.5.1 for me BUT: you have to use the 32bits version of the JVM. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe on my system)

Comment: Just for reference, 5.13.2 can be installed by executing the InstallService directly in x64.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here as I had the issue with ActiveMQ 5.5.1 but a different error when starting the service (something like 'could not create a tmp folder').

The solution is quite simple. I found it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2946

Basically, you jut have to create manually two folders:

{amq-home}/bin/win32/work
and 
{amq-home}/bin/win32/temp

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Though I shouldn't have to do this IMO. Why doesn't ActiveMQ create them for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install and run ActiveMQ 5.7.0 as a windows service, they forgot to include the wrapper.jar file into the release. You need to download the release ActiveMQ 5.6.0, take wrapper.jar from the BIN folder of this release, and copy it to the corresponding BIN folder of 5.7.0. Then it should work. Don't forget that you need to run the service installation script as administrator (right-click the BAT file, Run As Administrator)

Comment: Sounds like this is the main issue with installing the latest ActiveMQ 5.7.0 as a service: [link](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-5-7-0-startup-error-wrapper-jar-td4657797.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using procrun (see answer by LostInComputer above), you may need to add the following JVM options when installing the service, in order for the ${activemq.conf} and ${activemq.data} variables to resolve properly upon service startup:

++JvmOptions=-Dactivemq.conf=C:\Java\apache-activemq-5.7.0\conf ++JvmOptions=-Dactivemq.data=C:\Java\apache-activemq-5.7.0\data

Substitute absolute paths in snippet with your own installation paths.